# Date Month Year Dropdown Type Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, frontend

Is there a way to create a date picker with all three dropdowns (For date month and year) where I can restrict the minimum age entered to 18 years WITH JS/Frontend validation?

Comment: wat you need... please explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
$('#dob2').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function(dateText, inst) {
var dob = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
var age = GetAge(dob);
if (age >= 16 && age < 18) {
      alert("The minimum age requirement for supplementary card applicant is 18 years old. For applicant aged 16 and 17, and are going overseas to study, please submit the letter of acceptance from the education institution.");
   }
});

function GetAge(birthDate) {
var today = new Date();
var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
}
return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXEHp/720/)

```js
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear() - 18;
d.setFullYear(year);

   $("#lastReporteddate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: year,
      minDate: "-100Y",
            yearRange: '-100:' + year + '',
            defaultDate: d
   });
     $("#lastReportedmonth").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: year,
      minDate: "-100Y",
            yearRange: '-100:' + year + '',
            defaultDate: d
   });
     $("#lastReportedyear").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: year,
      minDate: "-100Y",
            yearRange: '-100:' + year + '',
            defaultDate: d
   });

$("#button").click(function(){
        var dob = $("#lastReporteddate").val();
        var mob = $("#lastReportedmonth").val();
        var yob = $("#lastReportedyear").val();
        var now = new Date();
        /* var birthdate = dob.split("/"); */
        var born = new Date(yob, mob-1, dob);
        age=get_age(born,now);
     
        console.log(yob+" : "+mob+" : "+dob);
        console.log(born);
      console.log(age);
        
        if (age<=18)
        {
       alert("Input Error - Age should be greater then or equal to 18");
            return false;
        }
});


    function get_age(born, now) {
      var birthday = new Date(now.getFullYear(), born.getMonth(), born.getDate());
      if (now >= birthday) 
        return now.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear();
      else
        return now.getFullYear() - born.getFullYear() - 1;
    }
```

```html
Date of Birth (DD): 
 <input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="lastReporteddate"/>
 Month (MM):
 <input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="lastReportedmonth"/>
 Year of Birth (YYYY):
 <input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" name="BirthDate" id="lastReportedyear"/>
<input type="submit" id="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript / jquery:

**Jquery**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="date" name="yourfieldname" class="hidden">
<select class="chan" id="d">
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
</select>
<select class="chan" id="m">
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<select class="chan" id="y">
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('change',".chan",function () {
            $("#date").val($("#d").val()+"/"+$("#m").val()+"/"+$("#y").val());
        })
    })
</script>
```